# How to get certain cell of datatables when every row comes from foreach?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, laravel-blade

I want to update cell dynamiclly by ajax,here is my table.

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
<tr >
    <th hidden> id</th>
    <th>custname</th>
    <th>custaddress</th>
    <th>custcity</th>
    <th>custcontact</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

@foreach($customers as $customer)
    <tr>
        <td class="cust_id" hidden>
            <div contenteditable="true" class="text" >{!! $customer['cust_id'] !!}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="cust_name">
            <div contenteditable="true" class="text" onblur="alert_value()">{!! $customer['cust_name'] !!}</div>
        </td>
        <td  class="cust_address" >
            <span  contenteditable="true" class="text">{!! $customer['cust_address'] !!}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cust_city" >
            <span contenteditable="true" class="text">{!! $customer['cust_city'] !!}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="cust_contact" id="text">
            <span contenteditable="true" class="text">{!! $customer['cust_contact']!!}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

how can I get certain cell in the table,how should I set the class or id ?It's annoying me..Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then do so.. What is the concern ? You have invalid markup! You are missing `<tr>` in `loop`

Comment: I've edit......@Rayon

Comment: My concern is how to get certain cell by jquery? @Rayon